# Jmeter Get ssl handshake certificate data

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to get ssl handshake data using jmeter?
I need to send number of ssl requests and get - SAN Subject Alternative Name, to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no particular sampler that could do it for you (at least no one I know about, someone correct me if I'm wrong).

So to my understanding you got two ways there:

1) Implement handshake process with sequence of [TCP Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) + [RegExp Extractor post processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) (+ custom [BeanShell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor)/[JSR223](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) post processors as needed) + appropriate [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions).

Don't forget to keep connection in every sampler in the chain if you go this way.

2) Implement a very custom Sampler in [BeanShell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler)/[Groovy(JSR223)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler).

Here, you, in turn, have two options:

- Implement it yourself step by step with Java Sockets (full control, but hell lot of work & errorproneness)
- Try to mess with [javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html). You have to implement a [HandshakeCompletedListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HandshakeCompletedListener.html) there (and register it with SSLSocket then), which would receive the [HandshakeCompletedEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HandshakeCompletedEvent.html) through which you, hopefully, can extract what you need using [SSLSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html)

P.S. I would like to ask you for a favor of sharing the results here, if you choose to go second way, especially SSLSocket case.